# How to use aws-codebuid batch?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to install my nodejs project (using yarn/npm) and then parallel typescript complition and linting at the same time:

- I need the `node_modules` folder to exist when running `build-typescript` and `lint` tasks.

buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2

batch:
  fast-fail: true
  build-graph:
    - identifier: install-yarn
      buildspec: .aws-codebuild-specs/install-yarn.yml

    - identifier: build-typescript
      buildspec: .aws-codebuild-specs/build-typescript.yml
      depend-on:
        - install-yarn

    - identifier: lint
      buildspec: .aws-codebuild-specs/lint.yml
      depend-on:
        - install-yarn
```

Aws codebuild error:

```
Phases found in YAML: 0
```

## Question

I'm failing to find a full simple example online.
What is the problem?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Randell No. Sorry..

Comment: I've never been able to get the `build-graph` option to work.  I've gotten `build-matrix` working just fine.  I kind of wonder if the feature simply doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when building an AWS CodePipeline. It seems that you need to tell the build step that you are running a batch build so the build runner knows to use that instead of the single build run. I updated my stage to add the `BatchEnabled` property to my configuration.

```
Stages:
    - Name: Build
      Actions:
      - Name: Build
        ActionTypeId:
          Category: Build
          Owner: AWS
          Version: 1
          Provider: CodeBuild
        Configuration:
          ProjectName: !Ref BuildRunner
          BatchEnabled: true
        InputArtifacts:
          - Name: SourceCode
        RunOrder: 1
```

When you start running the builds you'll see the builds under the Batch History of the build runner.